# Integrating Google Analytics with Salesforce Live Agent

Tags: integration, google, chat

We have built the chat page using Pre-chat VF page. This is deployed in the website and is working fine. Now we would like to integrate GA on the chat page and Salesforce. Is this possible? Have anybody worked on the same.
I searched various places, there are only questions, no answers!

Comment: Yes, there is nothing special about doing this. Just integrate as you would with any other page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you provide some examples how this can be done?